# Forcing autostart application on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, linux, qt, raspberry-pi3

I have gone through the related questions on stackoverflow and on the internet but can't find a suitable way to do this.

I have made a GUI application for raspberry pi3 running Raspbian OS. I want it to autostart when Raspberry boots up automatically. And stop the user from closing it, minimizing it etc.

In the meanwhile, the same raspberry pi is hosting a backend website on Apache 2 server for the administrator to change preferences by logging in on local LAN. I want this unchanged.

I want to discuss 2 cases:

**CASE 1:**
The GUI application is QT.

**CASE 2:**
The GUI application is an HTML website opened on internet browser. I want the browser address bar to be hidden so the user can't navigate away from the page.

**CASE 3:**
Any other way to make the GUI application you can suggest which will serve better in this application.

Thank you!

Comment: What difficult is that you want to prevent user from closing it or minimizing it. An alternative is to capture all key board events with full-screen launch.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Do a web search for "Raspian kiosk mode." Fundamentally, you need to modify the X startup so that it launches you app rather than a desktop. Because there will probably be no window manager, your app needs to be capable of being told to run in full-screen mode (e.g., using command-line arguments). There are various ways to accomplish all this, but the details depend on the exact release of Raspian you have.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a browser in a **kiosk** mode.

You didn't specify which browser you're using so here is example for chromium browser:

```
chromium-browser --kiosk --touch-events=enabled --disable-pinch --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --app=http://localhost/
```

This should basically turn off any address bars, errors dialogs after improper shutdowns etc.

Also check [FullPageOS](https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS) which is a distribution build specially for displaying one webpage in fullscreen on RPI